# Android studio 2.1.2 does not debug a program at Android device

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I use:

```
Windows 7 64 bit, 
Android Studio 2.1.2
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode).
```

My app works fine on my mobile and on Android Emulator. 
However when I tried to run debug mode on my Android phone nothing happened. 
I made several breakpoints where the program has to stopb but it ignores my breakpoints. 
Please help me, if I need to provide additional information let me know.

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.justjava"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Dose the break points work on emulator?

Comment: No. At the emulator, I get error:  Exeption={ErrnoException@3973}. And debug does not start at all. But app run ok on an emulator.

Comment: I see. Can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: @nshmura I have updated my firs post and list there build.gradle

Comment: Have you tried to attach the debugger to the running application (you could find it under the "Run" menu)? If so, there is still no result?

Comment: @VladimirZuyev Thanks. I'll post an answer for debug.

Comment: @nshmura thank you, I read it. But it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try like this:

1. Select `debug` Build Flavor.
   [image]
2. Set break point at the code always execute.
   ex) Activity's onCreate method.
   [image]
3. Run as Debug. (Select Menu -> Run -> Debug in AndroidStudio)
4. Execution will be stopped at the break point.

Comment: I set break point at the code that always execute. I put a lot of break point. But when I run debug - all of them are ignored and program doesn't stop. And this is my problem.